# Find SUM of an array of managed objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I have a big problem with taking a simple **Total Cost** from an array!

I have an entity called `currentCost`, it contains two attributes: `costAmount` and `costDesc`. I bind it to an array controller and I have no problem when I add and remove items to and from this entity. The problem is to get the **Total Cost** from the `costAmount` attributes and show it in a text field.

I think I have to fetch all `costAmount`s to another array and take the total of them, but it seems I don't know how to do this!  What is the best approach ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the text field to the array controller and specify `@sum.costAmount` as the key path.

Comment: Yeah, That's right dude ! 
Problem is now solved. BUT, there is something more than **@sum.costAmont** to do to solve it.
for other guys  that are have this situation I have to told, there is some very simple steps to solve the problem :
1- creat an **ArrayController** related to the entity.  
2- bind **textField** _value_ to the **ArrayController** . 
3- set the **Control key** to **arangedObjects** .  
4- set the **Model Key Path** to **@sum.attribute** [1]  
5- Enjoy it !  .
Thank you Bavarious
[1]Name of the attribute that you want to take it's summation